# How to install downloaded software?

Tags: installation, ffmpeg

Sometimes I download some software, and instead of an installer, I am faced with what looks like a folder containing the source code of the software. To see exactly what I mean, I am trying currently trying to install [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), and the download is just a folder of the source code.

My trouble is, I have absolutely no idea how to install it. I can't seem to figure it out from reading the `README.md` files in such downloads, and I just can't think of how to install it.

Sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question, I've just been stumped by this a few times in the last week!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg only provides the source code, but there are some users who compile it and provide executable files for download. Links to these for Windows, macOS, and Linux are on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page under "Get the Packages". So all you need to do is download, extract, and execute.

If you want to run the `ffmpeg` command from any directory the executable file has to be in your `PATH`. How to do this depends on your OS and there are plenty of Q/A here dealing with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting an installer and am not familiar with installing from files, I will take a wild guess and think you use Windows.

At the [ffmpeg page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) you linked in your question, underneath the huge green button, at center left, are three buttons with the icons for Linux (red), Windows (blue), and MacOS (grey). Scroll down, hover over the blue icon for Windows, then click on Builds [which will take you to here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Click on **Windows 64-bit** in the middle, then **Version 20191016-29dac29** (*or any greater number*), and the blue **Download Build** button. This downloads a ZIP file.

Open that zip file, and copy its folder below **C:\Program Files** then rename that folder to *ffmpeg*.

Add **C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin** [to your Path](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/), reboot the PC, and now you can run `ffmpeg` from a Windows Command Prompt.

You may also wish to consider a GUI to add to ffmpeg. [Here is a list](https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg%20Windows%20GUI).